# Normal variables declared under __init__

Tags: python, class, object, variables, init

In the example seen below, I have declared an object, obj1, using my class, Classy.
When obj1 is initialized, I declare a variable using self.var and I have an instance object that I can print to the console. All straight forward.

My question is around the other variable I have set, named variable. Running my code produces no errors, but I have (seemingly) no way of accessing it. It is neither a class variable of Classy, nor an instance variable is obj1.

Where is variable?

```
class Classy:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.var = value
        variable = 1


obj1 = Classy("object")
print(obj1.var)
```

> > > object

Comment: It existed only in `__init__`'s scope when it was executed... then went bye-bye.

Comment: "Normal" variables created inside a function or method are called local variables and exist while it's running.

Comment: (1/2) It seems like this question comes from a mistaken belief that there is something "magical" about `__init__` that makes `variable` different from any other local variable defined in a function. There isn't: `__init__` is no different from any other method.

Comment: (2/2) The apparent  magic around it being called without being called explicitly is just a consequence of how `type.__call__` is defined. When you use `Classy()`, there is a call to `type.__call__(Classy)`, which in turn calls `rv = Classy.__new__(Classy)`, and based on the type of its return value, `type.__call__` decides whether or not to call `type(rv).__init__(rv)` or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable named `variable` is a local variable. Specifically, it's local to the `__init__()` method. You won't be able to access it outside of that method. You can only access it inside of the method. Local variables created inside of the `__init__()` method really only serve the purpose of creating other instance variables:

```
class Classy:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.var = value
        variable = 1
        self.new_var = variable + 1 # new_var is 2


obj1 = Classy("object")
print(obj1.var)
```

Answer (score 1):

the variable `variable` is scoped to the function.  when you return from the function it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute "variable" is a local attribute that you can only access inside of the __init__() method. Indeed if you modify your class adding "print(locals)"

class classy:

```
def __init__(self,value):
    self.var = value
    variable = 1
    print(locals())
```

you can see that this attribute exists inside of the method. But if you get an instance of your class and then write

```
c = classy(10)
print(c.__dict__)
```

or

```
print(dir(c))
```

you can see that "variable" is not declared in the instance scope. So, "variable" is still a dynamic attribute because you wrote it inside of a method (it is not static) but the difference between it and "var" is that you can only use "variable" inside of **init**() method.

You can try to write

```
class classy:
    
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.var = value
        variable = 1
        
    def __increment__(self):
        self.var +=variable

c = classy(10)
c.__increment__() # NameError: name 'variable' is not defined
```

and see that you can neither use it inside of another method in the same class.